# Create python colorbar without plot

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter, colorbar

I used opencv colormaps on grayscale images. Now i need to show a colorbar, that represents the colormaps used in the colored image. As far as i know you can only create colorbars with plots. Is there any way to display a colorbar on a tkinter canvas without a plot?

I tried to create a plot and make it not visible but there is always some empty white space where the plot should be, when turned visible.

Comment: do you mean witout plot function ?

Comment: The tutorial has many examples of a colorbar without an associated plot. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, somehow i missed that. Exactly what i needed!